# Xamarin/Android, how to when click Back activity, value in the MainActivity will change

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Suppose in the MainActivity I have a TextView called "Your Name" and also SharedPreferences and a Button "Change Name" which will go to Activity 2.

The Activity 2 will show a textbox "Your Name" and after modify and click button "Save".

The SharedPreferences will be applied.

How to make sure that after Click "Save" and SharedPreferences is edited and when I click "Back" activity/button, the "Your Name" TextView will change?

The current issue I am having is that, I would need to close the app and open again to see the changes of "Your Name".

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make sure that after Click "Save" and SharedPreferences is edited and when I click "Back" activity/button, the "Your Name" TextView will change?

You can override the `OnResume` method in your `MainActivity`, for example:

Main.axml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your Name:" />

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/showName" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="change name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

code behind:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private TextView nametv;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        nametv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.showName);

        Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn);
        btn.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(Activity2));
        };
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        var preferences = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        //set text, if "Your name" is null, set default value "Empty"
        nametv.Text = preferences.GetString("Your Name", "Empty");
    }
}
```

Code in `Activity2` for saving the `SharedPreferences` can be like this:

```
EditText etname = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etname);
Button saveBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.saveBtn);
saveBtn.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (etname.Text != null)
    {
        var preferences = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        var editor = preferences.Edit();
        editor.PutString("Your Name", etname.Text);
        editor.Commit();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please explain meaning of Override the OnResume method in your MainActivity? Thanks

Comment: @David, that you may need to understand the [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) of android activity.